# Continuous Count Up on Odometer JS

Tags: javascript, odometer

I am using OdometerJS (https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/) to animate a php value from an xml file and it is working great, however after the value gets to where it needs to be, I want it to count up by the cents, to look like the number is growing.

```js
/*! odometer 0.4.6 */
(function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G=[].slice;q='<span class="odometer-value"></span>',n='<span class="odometer-ribbon"><span class="odometer-ribbon-inner">'+q+"</span></span>",d='<span class="odometer-digit"><span class="odometer-digit-spacer">8</span><span class="odometer-digit-inner">'+n+"</span></span>",g='<span class="odometer-formatting-mark"></span>',c="(,ddd).dd",h=/^\(?([^)]*)\)?(?:(.)(d+))?$/,i=30,f=2e3,a=20,j=2,e=.5,k=1e3/i,b=1e3/a,o="transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",y=document.createElement("div").style,p=null!=y.transition||null!=y.webkitTransition||null!=y.mozTransition||null!=y.oTransition,w=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame,l=window.MutationObserver||window.WebKitMutationObserver||window.MozMutationObserver,s=function(a){var b;return b=document.createElement("div"),b.innerHTML=a,b.children[0]},v=function(a,b){return a.className=a.className.replace(new RegExp("(^| )"+b.split(" ").join("|")+"( |$)","gi")," ")},r=function(a,b){return v(a,b),a.className+=" "+b},z=function(a,b){var c;return null!=document.createEvent?(c=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"),c.initEvent(b,!0,!0),a.dispatchEvent(c)):void 0},u=function(){var a,b;return null!=(a=null!=(b=window.performance)?"function"==typeof b.now?b.now():void 0:void 0)?a:+new Date},x=function(a,b){return null==b&&(b=0),b?(a*=Math.pow(10,b),a+=.5,a=Math.floor(a),a/=Math.pow(10,b)):Math.round(a)},A=function(a){return 0>a?Math.ceil(a):Math.floor(a)},t=function(a){return a-x(a)},C=!1,(B=function(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(!C&&null!=window.jQuery){for(C=!0,d=["html","text"],e=[],b=0,c=d.length;c>b;b++)a=d[b],e.push(function(a){var b;return b=window.jQuery.fn[a],window.jQuery.fn[a]=function(a){var c;return null==a||null==(null!=(c=this[0])?c.odometer:void 0)?b.apply(this,arguments):this[0].odometer.update(a)}}(a));return e}})(),setTimeout(B,0),m=function(){function a(b){var c,d,e,g,h,i,l,m,n,o,p=this;if(this.options=b,this.el=this.options.el,null!=this.el.odometer)return this.el.odometer;this.el.odometer=this,m=a.options;for(d in m)g=m[d],null==this.options[d]&&(this.options[d]=g);null==(h=this.options).duration&&(h.duration=f),this.MAX_VALUES=this.options.duration/k/j|0,this.resetFormat(),this.value=this.cleanValue(null!=(n=this.options.value)?n:""),this.renderInside(),this.render();try{for(o=["innerHTML","innerText","textContent"],i=0,l=o.length;l>i;i++)e=o[i],null!=this.el[e]&&!function(a){return Object.defineProperty(p.el,a,{get:function(){var b;return"innerHTML"===a?p.inside.outerHTML:null!=(b=p.inside.innerText)?b:p.inside.textContent},set:function(a){return p.update(a)}})}(e)}catch(q){c=q,this.watchForMutations()}}return a.prototype.renderInside=function(){return this.inside=document.createElement("div"),this.inside.className="odometer-inside",this.el.innerHTML="",this.el.appendChild(this.inside)},a.prototype.watchForMutations=function(){var a,b=this;if(null!=l)try{return null==this.observer&&(this.observer=new l(function(){var a;return a=b.el.innerText,b.renderInside(),b.render(b.value),b.update(a)})),this.watchMutations=!0,this.startWatchingMutations()}catch(c){a=c}},a.prototype.startWatchingMutations=function(){return this.watchMutations?this.observer.observe(this.el,{childList:!0}):void 0},a.prototype.stopWatchingMutations=function(){var a;return null!=(a=this.observer)?a.disconnect():void 0},a.prototype.cleanValue=function(a){var b;return"string"==typeof a&&(a=a.replace(null!=(b=this.format.radix)?b:".","<radix>"),a=a.replace(/[.,]/g,""),a=a.replace("<radix>","."),a=parseFloat(a,10)||0),x(a,this.format.precision)},a.prototype.bindTransitionEnd=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g=this;if(!this.transitionEndBound){for(this.transitionEndBound=!0,b=!1,e=o.split(" "),f=[],c=0,d=e.length;d>c;c++)a=e[c],f.push(this.el.addEventListener(a,function(){return b?!0:(b=!0,setTimeout(function(){return g.render(),b=!1,z(g.el,"odometerdone")},0),!0)},!1));return f}},a.prototype.resetFormat=function(){var a,b,d,e,f,g,i,j;if(a=null!=(i=this.options.format)?i:c,a||(a="d"),d=h.exec(a),!d)throw new Error("Odometer: Unparsable digit format");return j=d.slice(1,4),g=j[0],f=j[1],b=j[2],e=(null!=b?b.length:void 0)||0,this.format={repeating:g,radix:f,precision:e}},a.prototype.render=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m;for(null==a&&(a=this.value),this.stopWatchingMutations(),this.resetFormat(),this.inside.innerHTML="",g=this.options.theme,b=this.el.className.split(" "),f=[],i=0,k=b.length;k>i;i++)c=b[i],c.length&&((e=/^odometer-theme-(.+)$/.exec(c))?g=e[1]:/^odometer(-|$)/.test(c)||f.push(c));for(f.push("odometer"),p||f.push("odometer-no-transitions"),f.push(g?"odometer-theme-"+g:"odometer-auto-theme"),this.el.className=f.join(" "),this.ribbons={},this.digits=[],h=!this.format.precision||!t(a)||!1,m=a.toString().split("").reverse(),j=0,l=m.length;l>j;j++)d=m[j],"."===d&&(h=!0),this.addDigit(d,h);return this.startWatchingMutations()},a.prototype.update=function(a){var b,c=this;return a=this.cleanValue(a),(b=a-this.value)?(v(this.el,"odometer-animating-up odometer-animating-down odometer-animating"),b>0?r(this.el,"odometer-animating-up"):r(this.el,"odometer-animating-down"),this.stopWatchingMutations(),this.animate(a),this.startWatchingMutations(),setTimeout(function(){return c.el.offsetHeight,r(c.el,"odometer-animating")},0),this.value=a):void 0},a.prototype.renderDigit=function(){return s(d)},a.prototype.insertDigit=function(a,b){return null!=b?this.inside.insertBefore(a,b):this.inside.children.length?this.inside.insertBefore(a,this.inside.children[0]):this.inside.appendChild(a)},a.prototype.addSpacer=function(a,b,c){var d;return d=s(g),d.innerHTML=a,c&&r(d,c),this.insertDigit(d,b)},a.prototype.addDigit=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f;if(null==b&&(b=!0),"-"===a)return this.addSpacer(a,null,"odometer-negation-mark");if("."===a)return this.addSpacer(null!=(f=this.format.radix)?f:".",null,"odometer-radix-mark");if(b)for(e=!1;;){if(!this.format.repeating.length){if(e)throw new Error("Bad odometer format without digits");this.resetFormat(),e=!0}if(c=this.format.repeating[this.format.repeating.length-1],this.format.repeating=this.format.repeating.substring(0,this.format.repeating.length-1),"d"===c)break;this.addSpacer(c)}return d=this.renderDigit(),d.querySelector(".odometer-value").innerHTML=a,this.digits.push(d),this.insertDigit(d)},a.prototype.animate=function(a){return p&&"count"!==this.options.animation?this.animateSlide(a):this.animateCount(a)},a.prototype.animateCount=function(a){var c,d,e,f,g,h=this;if(d=+a-this.value)return f=e=u(),c=this.value,(g=function(){var i,j,k;return u()-f>h.options.duration?(h.value=a,h.render(),void z(h.el,"odometerdone")):(i=u()-e,i>b&&(e=u(),k=i/h.options.duration,j=d*k,c+=j,h.render(Math.round(c))),null!=w?w(g):setTimeout(g,b))})()},a.prototype.getDigitCount=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f;for(d=1<=arguments.length?G.call(arguments,0):[],a=e=0,f=d.length;f>e;a=++e)c=d[a],d[a]=Math.abs(c);return b=Math.max.apply(Math,d),Math.ceil(Math.log(b+1)/Math.log(10))},a.prototype.getFractionalDigitCount=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g;for(e=1<=arguments.length?G.call(arguments,0):[],b=/^\-?\d*\.(\d*?)0*$/,a=f=0,g=e.length;g>f;a=++f)d=e[a],e[a]=d.toString(),c=b.exec(e[a]),e[a]=null==c?0:c[1].length;return Math.max.apply(Math,e)},a.prototype.resetDigits=function(){return this.digits=[],this.ribbons=[],this.inside.innerHTML="",this.resetFormat()},a.prototype.animateSlide=function(a){var b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,B,C,D,E;if(s=this.value,j=this.getFractionalDigitCount(s,a),j&&(a*=Math.pow(10,j),s*=Math.pow(10,j)),d=a-s){for(this.bindTransitionEnd(),f=this.getDigitCount(s,a),g=[],b=0,m=v=0;f>=0?f>v:v>f;m=f>=0?++v:--v){if(t=A(s/Math.pow(10,f-m-1)),i=A(a/Math.pow(10,f-m-1)),h=i-t,Math.abs(h)>this.MAX_VALUES){for(l=[],n=h/(this.MAX_VALUES+this.MAX_VALUES*b*e),c=t;h>0&&i>c||0>h&&c>i;)l.push(Math.round(c)),c+=n;l[l.length-1]!==i&&l.push(i),b++}else l=function(){E=[];for(var a=t;i>=t?i>=a:a>=i;i>=t?a++:a--)E.push(a);return E}.apply(this);for(m=w=0,y=l.length;y>w;m=++w)k=l[m],l[m]=Math.abs(k%10);g.push(l)}for(this.resetDigits(),D=g.reverse(),m=x=0,z=D.length;z>x;m=++x)for(l=D[m],this.digits[m]||this.addDigit(" ",m>=j),null==(u=this.ribbons)[m]&&(u[m]=this.digits[m].querySelector(".odometer-ribbon-inner")),this.ribbons[m].innerHTML="",0>d&&(l=l.reverse()),o=C=0,B=l.length;B>C;o=++C)k=l[o],q=document.createElement("div"),q.className="odometer-value",q.innerHTML=k,this.ribbons[m].appendChild(q),o===l.length-1&&r(q,"odometer-last-value"),0===o&&r(q,"odometer-first-value");return 0>t&&this.addDigit("-"),p=this.inside.querySelector(".odometer-radix-mark"),null!=p&&p.parent.removeChild(p),j?this.addSpacer(this.format.radix,this.digits[j-1],"odometer-radix-mark"):void 0}},a}(),m.options=null!=(E=window.odometerOptions)?E:{},setTimeout(function(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(window.odometerOptions){d=window.odometerOptions,e=[];for(a in d)b=d[a],e.push(null!=(c=m.options)[a]?(c=m.options)[a]:c[a]=b);return e}},0),m.init=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f;if(null!=document.querySelectorAll){for(b=document.querySelectorAll(m.options.selector||".odometer"),f=[],c=0,d=b.length;d>c;c++)a=b[c],f.push(a.odometer=new m({el:a,value:null!=(e=a.innerText)?e:a.textContent}));return f}},null!=(null!=(F=document.documentElement)?F.doScroll:void 0)&&null!=document.createEventObject?(D=document.onreadystatechange,document.onreadystatechange=function(){return"complete"===document.readyState&&m.options.auto!==!1&&m.init(),null!=D?D.apply(this,arguments):void 0}):document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){return m.options.auto!==!1?m.init():void 0},!1),"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],function(){return m}):typeof exports===!1?module.exports=m:window.Odometer=m}).call(this);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="odometer.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css" />
 
 <script>
window.odometerOptions = {
  format: '(,ddd).dd'
 
};
</script>



$<div class="odometer">0000.00</div>

    <script>
    // var finalDigit = '<?php echo $value10 ?>';
    var finalDigit = 1508.19;
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.odometer').html(finalDigit);
      }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Example of what I am trying to achieve:  https://maryland.livecasinohotel.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set another timer or interval and just feed it an updated value.  It seems to animate from the previously set value to the new:

```js
/*! odometer 0.4.6 */
(function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G=[].slice;q='<span class="odometer-value"></span>',n='<span class="odometer-ribbon"><span class="odometer-ribbon-inner">'+q+"</span></span>",d='<span class="odometer-digit"><span class="odometer-digit-spacer">8</span><span class="odometer-digit-inner">'+n+"</span></span>",g='<span class="odometer-formatting-mark"></span>',c="(,ddd).dd",h=/^\(?([^)]*)\)?(?:(.)(d+))?$/,i=30,f=2e3,a=20,j=2,e=.5,k=1e3/i,b=1e3/a,o="transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",y=document.createElement("div").style,p=null!=y.transition||null!=y.webkitTransition||null!=y.mozTransition||null!=y.oTransition,w=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame,l=window.MutationObserver||window.WebKitMutationObserver||window.MozMutationObserver,s=function(a){var b;return b=document.createElement("div"),b.innerHTML=a,b.children[0]},v=function(a,b){return a.className=a.className.replace(new RegExp("(^| )"+b.split(" ").join("|")+"( |$)","gi")," ")},r=function(a,b){return v(a,b),a.className+=" "+b},z=function(a,b){var c;return null!=document.createEvent?(c=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"),c.initEvent(b,!0,!0),a.dispatchEvent(c)):void 0},u=function(){var a,b;return null!=(a=null!=(b=window.performance)?"function"==typeof b.now?b.now():void 0:void 0)?a:+new Date},x=function(a,b){return null==b&&(b=0),b?(a*=Math.pow(10,b),a+=.5,a=Math.floor(a),a/=Math.pow(10,b)):Math.round(a)},A=function(a){return 0>a?Math.ceil(a):Math.floor(a)},t=function(a){return a-x(a)},C=!1,(B=function(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(!C&&null!=window.jQuery){for(C=!0,d=["html","text"],e=[],b=0,c=d.length;c>b;b++)a=d[b],e.push(function(a){var b;return b=window.jQuery.fn[a],window.jQuery.fn[a]=function(a){var c;return null==a||null==(null!=(c=this[0])?c.odometer:void 0)?b.apply(this,arguments):this[0].odometer.update(a)}}(a));return e}})(),setTimeout(B,0),m=function(){function a(b){var c,d,e,g,h,i,l,m,n,o,p=this;if(this.options=b,this.el=this.options.el,null!=this.el.odometer)return this.el.odometer;this.el.odometer=this,m=a.options;for(d in m)g=m[d],null==this.options[d]&&(this.options[d]=g);null==(h=this.options).duration&&(h.duration=f),this.MAX_VALUES=this.options.duration/k/j|0,this.resetFormat(),this.value=this.cleanValue(null!=(n=this.options.value)?n:""),this.renderInside(),this.render();try{for(o=["innerHTML","innerText","textContent"],i=0,l=o.length;l>i;i++)e=o[i],null!=this.el[e]&&!function(a){return Object.defineProperty(p.el,a,{get:function(){var b;return"innerHTML"===a?p.inside.outerHTML:null!=(b=p.inside.innerText)?b:p.inside.textContent},set:function(a){return p.update(a)}})}(e)}catch(q){c=q,this.watchForMutations()}}return a.prototype.renderInside=function(){return this.inside=document.createElement("div"),this.inside.className="odometer-inside",this.el.innerHTML="",this.el.appendChild(this.inside)},a.prototype.watchForMutations=function(){var a,b=this;if(null!=l)try{return null==this.observer&&(this.observer=new l(function(){var a;return a=b.el.innerText,b.renderInside(),b.render(b.value),b.update(a)})),this.watchMutations=!0,this.startWatchingMutations()}catch(c){a=c}},a.prototype.startWatchingMutations=function(){return this.watchMutations?this.observer.observe(this.el,{childList:!0}):void 0},a.prototype.stopWatchingMutations=function(){var a;return null!=(a=this.observer)?a.disconnect():void 0},a.prototype.cleanValue=function(a){var b;return"string"==typeof a&&(a=a.replace(null!=(b=this.format.radix)?b:".","<radix>"),a=a.replace(/[.,]/g,""),a=a.replace("<radix>","."),a=parseFloat(a,10)||0),x(a,this.format.precision)},a.prototype.bindTransitionEnd=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g=this;if(!this.transitionEndBound){for(this.transitionEndBound=!0,b=!1,e=o.split(" "),f=[],c=0,d=e.length;d>c;c++)a=e[c],f.push(this.el.addEventListener(a,function(){return b?!0:(b=!0,setTimeout(function(){return g.render(),b=!1,z(g.el,"odometerdone")},0),!0)},!1));return f}},a.prototype.resetFormat=function(){var a,b,d,e,f,g,i,j;if(a=null!=(i=this.options.format)?i:c,a||(a="d"),d=h.exec(a),!d)throw new Error("Odometer: Unparsable digit format");return j=d.slice(1,4),g=j[0],f=j[1],b=j[2],e=(null!=b?b.length:void 0)||0,this.format={repeating:g,radix:f,precision:e}},a.prototype.render=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m;for(null==a&&(a=this.value),this.stopWatchingMutations(),this.resetFormat(),this.inside.innerHTML="",g=this.options.theme,b=this.el.className.split(" "),f=[],i=0,k=b.length;k>i;i++)c=b[i],c.length&&((e=/^odometer-theme-(.+)$/.exec(c))?g=e[1]:/^odometer(-|$)/.test(c)||f.push(c));for(f.push("odometer"),p||f.push("odometer-no-transitions"),f.push(g?"odometer-theme-"+g:"odometer-auto-theme"),this.el.className=f.join(" "),this.ribbons={},this.digits=[],h=!this.format.precision||!t(a)||!1,m=a.toString().split("").reverse(),j=0,l=m.length;l>j;j++)d=m[j],"."===d&&(h=!0),this.addDigit(d,h);return this.startWatchingMutations()},a.prototype.update=function(a){var b,c=this;return a=this.cleanValue(a),(b=a-this.value)?(v(this.el,"odometer-animating-up odometer-animating-down odometer-animating"),b>0?r(this.el,"odometer-animating-up"):r(this.el,"odometer-animating-down"),this.stopWatchingMutations(),this.animate(a),this.startWatchingMutations(),setTimeout(function(){return c.el.offsetHeight,r(c.el,"odometer-animating")},0),this.value=a):void 0},a.prototype.renderDigit=function(){return s(d)},a.prototype.insertDigit=function(a,b){return null!=b?this.inside.insertBefore(a,b):this.inside.children.length?this.inside.insertBefore(a,this.inside.children[0]):this.inside.appendChild(a)},a.prototype.addSpacer=function(a,b,c){var d;return d=s(g),d.innerHTML=a,c&&r(d,c),this.insertDigit(d,b)},a.prototype.addDigit=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f;if(null==b&&(b=!0),"-"===a)return this.addSpacer(a,null,"odometer-negation-mark");if("."===a)return this.addSpacer(null!=(f=this.format.radix)?f:".",null,"odometer-radix-mark");if(b)for(e=!1;;){if(!this.format.repeating.length){if(e)throw new Error("Bad odometer format without digits");this.resetFormat(),e=!0}if(c=this.format.repeating[this.format.repeating.length-1],this.format.repeating=this.format.repeating.substring(0,this.format.repeating.length-1),"d"===c)break;this.addSpacer(c)}return d=this.renderDigit(),d.querySelector(".odometer-value").innerHTML=a,this.digits.push(d),this.insertDigit(d)},a.prototype.animate=function(a){return p&&"count"!==this.options.animation?this.animateSlide(a):this.animateCount(a)},a.prototype.animateCount=function(a){var c,d,e,f,g,h=this;if(d=+a-this.value)return f=e=u(),c=this.value,(g=function(){var i,j,k;return u()-f>h.options.duration?(h.value=a,h.render(),void z(h.el,"odometerdone")):(i=u()-e,i>b&&(e=u(),k=i/h.options.duration,j=d*k,c+=j,h.render(Math.round(c))),null!=w?w(g):setTimeout(g,b))})()},a.prototype.getDigitCount=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f;for(d=1<=arguments.length?G.call(arguments,0):[],a=e=0,f=d.length;f>e;a=++e)c=d[a],d[a]=Math.abs(c);return b=Math.max.apply(Math,d),Math.ceil(Math.log(b+1)/Math.log(10))},a.prototype.getFractionalDigitCount=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g;for(e=1<=arguments.length?G.call(arguments,0):[],b=/^\-?\d*\.(\d*?)0*$/,a=f=0,g=e.length;g>f;a=++f)d=e[a],e[a]=d.toString(),c=b.exec(e[a]),e[a]=null==c?0:c[1].length;return Math.max.apply(Math,e)},a.prototype.resetDigits=function(){return this.digits=[],this.ribbons=[],this.inside.innerHTML="",this.resetFormat()},a.prototype.animateSlide=function(a){var b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,B,C,D,E;if(s=this.value,j=this.getFractionalDigitCount(s,a),j&&(a*=Math.pow(10,j),s*=Math.pow(10,j)),d=a-s){for(this.bindTransitionEnd(),f=this.getDigitCount(s,a),g=[],b=0,m=v=0;f>=0?f>v:v>f;m=f>=0?++v:--v){if(t=A(s/Math.pow(10,f-m-1)),i=A(a/Math.pow(10,f-m-1)),h=i-t,Math.abs(h)>this.MAX_VALUES){for(l=[],n=h/(this.MAX_VALUES+this.MAX_VALUES*b*e),c=t;h>0&&i>c||0>h&&c>i;)l.push(Math.round(c)),c+=n;l[l.length-1]!==i&&l.push(i),b++}else l=function(){E=[];for(var a=t;i>=t?i>=a:a>=i;i>=t?a++:a--)E.push(a);return E}.apply(this);for(m=w=0,y=l.length;y>w;m=++w)k=l[m],l[m]=Math.abs(k%10);g.push(l)}for(this.resetDigits(),D=g.reverse(),m=x=0,z=D.length;z>x;m=++x)for(l=D[m],this.digits[m]||this.addDigit(" ",m>=j),null==(u=this.ribbons)[m]&&(u[m]=this.digits[m].querySelector(".odometer-ribbon-inner")),this.ribbons[m].innerHTML="",0>d&&(l=l.reverse()),o=C=0,B=l.length;B>C;o=++C)k=l[o],q=document.createElement("div"),q.className="odometer-value",q.innerHTML=k,this.ribbons[m].appendChild(q),o===l.length-1&&r(q,"odometer-last-value"),0===o&&r(q,"odometer-first-value");return 0>t&&this.addDigit("-"),p=this.inside.querySelector(".odometer-radix-mark"),null!=p&&p.parent.removeChild(p),j?this.addSpacer(this.format.radix,this.digits[j-1],"odometer-radix-mark"):void 0}},a}(),m.options=null!=(E=window.odometerOptions)?E:{},setTimeout(function(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(window.odometerOptions){d=window.odometerOptions,e=[];for(a in d)b=d[a],e.push(null!=(c=m.options)[a]?(c=m.options)[a]:c[a]=b);return e}},0),m.init=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f;if(null!=document.querySelectorAll){for(b=document.querySelectorAll(m.options.selector||".odometer"),f=[],c=0,d=b.length;d>c;c++)a=b[c],f.push(a.odometer=new m({el:a,value:null!=(e=a.innerText)?e:a.textContent}));return f}},null!=(null!=(F=document.documentElement)?F.doScroll:void 0)&&null!=document.createEventObject?(D=document.onreadystatechange,document.onreadystatechange=function(){return"complete"===document.readyState&&m.options.auto!==!1&&m.init(),null!=D?D.apply(this,arguments):void 0}):document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){return m.options.auto!==!1?m.init():void 0},!1),"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],function(){return m}):typeof exports===!1?module.exports=m:window.Odometer=m}).call(this);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="odometer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css" />
 
<script>
  window.odometerOptions = {
    format: '(,ddd).dd'
  };
</script>

$<div class="odometer">0,000.00</div>

<script>
  // var finalDigit = '<?php echo $value10 ?>';
  var finalDigit = 1508.19;
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer').html(finalDigit);
  }, 500);
  setInterval(function(){
    finalDigit += 0.01;
    $('.odometer').html(finalDigit);
  }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: When I switch back to using the php variable as the final digit, the count up function doesn't work. The variable is the same format as the test number, 1508.19

Comment: Check the type, it might be in string format which might affect how its interpretted

Comment: hmm, ive tried changing it to an integer, a float, a number format etc. I've even tried stripping the decimals. If I strip the decimals it works, but adds an extra 0 before the decimal point when it adds in the .01.  The php value is the parsing of an xml file. the xml value is a number like 1508.19, not sure how else to try to format it.

Comment: Perhaps post the updated code, and the generated html from the browser?

Comment: Here is the code I am using, its parsing an xml feed of odometer values. http://codepad.org/CVP0eIWb

Comment: and here is the live code https://rewards.rampartcasino.net/reels/

Comment: When I load the live code link, in the browser console log I can see a repeated error message "Reference error: Can't find variable counter".  That is a `counter += 1` statement in the interval callback. I'm not sure what you were intending here as its not the code posted above, nor is it changing the value passed to `odometer.html()`

Comment: I was testing the code, and adding multiple instances since that will be my final product. Updated code here http://codepad.org/a1I3CyV3

Comment: I just looked at the live version which is reporting "Can't find variable six".  I appreciate you're probably working on this so looking at the live version is a bit hit and miss in understanding where your problem lies.  What I can see is that $num6 contains a string including a comma as the thousands separator, and you assign that to `finalDigit6`.  When you do `finalDigit6 += 0.01` you will be doing concatenation, resulting in, eg. `1,123.000.01`.  You need `finalDigit6` to be of type `number` to be able to do the increment.

Comment: e.g. `var finalDigit6 = parseFloat('<?php echo $num6 ?>'.replace(',', ''))`, or you could do the same in the PHP code when you extract the value, maybe what you were intending with the `preg_replace`.  If the `$num6` value is a number then you can remove the single quotes when you `echo` it into the script.